# Using Material UI is causing invalid hook call warning

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, rollupjs

I'm trying out [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) to bundle a reusable library. The idea I'm trying out is to create composable component libraries that we can use in our web app and our electron app.

In our package.json file we have the following requirements

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    ....
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
}
```

When I import a Material UI component it results in an error

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

This is the full component (it's just the example from create-react-library that I was slowly expanding on)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

import styles from './styles.css'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props

    return (

        <div className="">
          <Button></Button>
          Example Component: {text}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

********************************** Edit **********************************

Changing the devDependencies for material ui and react and adding to the rollup.config.js file (to deal with an issue that this introduced) fixed the error

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
    ...
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
   }
```

rollup.config.js

```
commonjs({
  include: 'node_modules/**',
  namedExports: {
    'node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/index.js': [
      'createGenerateClassName',
      'createMuiTheme',
      'createStyles',
      'jssPreset',
      'MuiThemeProvider',
      'withStyles',
      'withTheme'
    ],
    'node_modules/@material-ui/core/Modal/index.js': [ 'ModalManager' ]
  }
})
```

Comment: The error message itself is incomplete. Have you checked out the link and try to debug the issue with the help of the article?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'incomplete'; the error message is included in the ticket exactly as it appears to me. Yes, I've already tried debugging.

Comment: I meant to message that react is showing in the console. Did you read this article: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html?

Comment: Your devDependencies look problematic. Material-UI v4 has peerDependencies of "^16.8.0" for react and react-dom (i.e. requires hooks support). Your devDependencies should use "^16.8.0" or higher for react and react-dom.

Comment: @epsilon ...Yes. I answered your first comment stating that I read the article. I'm not going to post on stackoverflow without first doing research.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I think you're right. I got it to work moving the devDependencies down and adding to my rollup.config.js file to deal with issues that introduced. See updates in my issue

Comment: @islalobo Well your in the top percentile then and for the record you didn't state you read the article. You just said you did "debugging". I just recently had the same experience with this exact error where people claimed they investigated the issue but didn't read the article. Your answer can still be problematic since it lists react@^16.7. It should be ^16.8

Comment: @epsilon islalobo’s main change was to downgrade Material-Ui from the alpha to ^3.9.0, so it should be fine with 16.7 for react.

Comment: Can confirm that I have this issue too.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't this issue? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991 (ie. a general hooks issue, rather than material-ui)

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue using React 16.8 and Material 4.0. If I downgrade material to 3.9.X then everything works (but it has completely different changes in grid / typography so this is undesired). Was there any actual fix for this issue discovered?

Comment: @islalobo Did you find a good solution for this issue eventually?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a submodule installed with a `node_modules` folder, I was actually compiling react twice into a bundle.

**Fixed by removing submodule's node_modules** folder, could also potentially fix in webpack config:

```
   main
      node_modules
      submodules
          -> node_modules
```